# Function Calculations with Table Objects

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use some statistical excel functions like: *min*, *max*, *average*, *quartile*, etc; in combination with an excel table object. I want to be able to apply filters with the table and then have the functions find the value with the now filtered out data.

Neither of the attempts below seem to only find the value between what is filtered.

```
=MIN(Table2[TAT (days)])

=MIN(F62:F1048576)
```

I expected excel to calculate the min from the table object if I apply a filter on the table object for only the *filtered* values, but it always gives me the result for the entire *range*.[Data Table with the functions above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saglD.png)

Comment: You'll want to look into [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7B027003-F060-4ADE-9040-E478765B9939)

Comment: @L.A. You will increase the probability of getting a response, providing more contextual information about your problem. Take a look to this post: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad subtotal did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: =SUBTOTAL(5, RANGE) worker like a charm

Comment: Actually, the aggregate function allowed me to look for all the stats based on filters and all other sorts of conditions: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/aggregate.php